# VRP where only a subset of vertices needs to be visited

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

Hi just a quick question, I am looking at a VRP problem, where only a subset of costumers needs to be visited.

So given a complete graph G=(V,E) a fleet of vehicles needs to service a given number $n$ of customers, where $n \leq \lvert V \rvert$, I am having trouble finding literature on the subject, is this a well studied topic?

Comment: Must the vehicles be identical?

Comment: @RobPratt The vehicles are identical in my problem yes

Comment: Search for prize-collecting VRP.